# padding a list of torch tensors (or numpy arrays)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pytorch, padding

Let's say I have a list as the following:

```
l = [torch.randn(2,3), torch.randn(2,4),torch.randn(2,5)]
```

I want to zero pad all of them in the second dimension, so they will extend as far as 5 elements (5 being the max number between the three of the elements in the second dimension). How can I do this. I tried this but failed:

```
from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pad_sequence
pad_sequence(l, batch_first=True, padding_value=0)
```

which caused the following error:

```
RuntimeError: The expanded size of the tensor (3) must match the existing size (4) at non-singleton dimension 1.  Target sizes: [2, 3].  Tensor sizes: [2, 4]
```

The equivalent answer in Numpy would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use [`np.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html).

Example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randn(2, 3)
b = np.pad(a, [(0, 0), (0, 2)], mode='constant')
```

Print `a` gives

```
[[ 1.22721163  1.23456672  0.51948003]
 [ 0.16545496  0.06609003 -0.32071653]]
```

Print `b` gives

```
[[ 1.22721163  1.23456672  0.51948003  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.16545496  0.06609003 -0.32071653  0.          0.        ]]
```

The second argument of `pad` is `pad_width` which is a list of before/after paddings for each dimension. So in this example no padding in the first dimension and two paddings at the end of the second dimension.

There are lots of other `mode` options you can use so check out the docs.

For your particular problem you'll need to add an extra step to work out the padding for each array.

**Edit**

For `pytorch` I think you want [`torch.nn.functional.pad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#pad) e.g.

```
import torch
t = torch.randn(2, 3)
torch.nn.functional.pad(t, (0, 2))
```

**Edit 2**

The [`torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence) requires the trailing dimensions of all the tensors in the list to be the same so you need to some transposing for it to work nicely

```
import torch
# l = [torch.randn(2,3), torch.randn(2,4),torch.randn(2,5)]
# l = [i.transpose(0, 1) for i in l]  
# or simply make you tensors with switched dimensions
l = [torch.randn(3,2), torch.randn(4,2),torch.randn(5,2)]
out = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence(l, batch_first=True)
# out will now be a tensor with shape (3, 5, 2)
# You can transpose it back to (3, 2, 5) with
out = out.transpose(1, 2)
```